# How to specify a port number for a SMTP send adapter in BizTalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Trying to setup a SMTP send adapter in BizTalk 2010. When I specify the server name along with the port also (ex: mailserver.xxx.com:8989), mails do not go out. Otherwise they do. I couldn't find anything online about an issue with specifying the port in the servername. Can anyone confirm that we can not provide the port number in SMTP server name?

In SSIS- Send Mail task, same behavior. We are not allowed to append the port number. Could this be a related issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, specifying a custom port for the SMTP Send Adapter is not possible.

To note, the BizTalk SMTP Adapter and the Send Mail task are completely different implementations so it's just an unhappy coincidence if neither support this.

One possible solution is to configure the Windows/IIS SMTP Service somewhere in the Group and let it relay the messages.

Comment: it seemed that way, can you point me to any official documentation confirming this? Thank you.

Comment: The only official documentation is that specifying a custom port is *not documented*.